# Payment Gateway using cURL with SSL?

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, credit-card

I am processing credit cards using a payment gateway.  To POST the data to their servers, I am using cURL in PHP.  I have an SSL certificate issued to my domain, to ensure all POST'ed data is encrypted.  Because the SSL certificate is already installed, do I still need to use the SSL options for cURL?  If so, which of the options do I need to set given my setup?

I have tried the following code unsuccessfully:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://secure.paymentgateway.com/blah.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,  getcwd().'/cert/ca.crt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd().'/cert/mycert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, 'password');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $count);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"variables...");                                                                 

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm just curious, could you specify which payment gateway it is?

Comment: payscape is the payment gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you already disabled the verification (which I don't recommend: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`). This opens you for Man-in-the-middle attacks.

Here's a simple tutorial that might help you:

http://developer.paypal-portal.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=ipn&message.id=12754#M12754